# "that"be replaced by "whom"

Tags: grammar

Q：
I think if "that" is the object of "say", then the word of "that" should also be replaced by "whom".
Am I right？

The analysis questions are as follows.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

> *Who (that understands music) can say that his playing is bad?*

The relative word is not object of "say", but subject of "understands", so "whom" is not possible.

"That" and "who" are both possible, though two consecutive "whos" sound odd.

The declarative content clause "that his playing is bad" functions as complement of "say", and has no bearing on the relative clause.